$\text{Rep}(D_4)$ and its three fiber functors
It is well-known that the fusion category $\text{Rep}(D_4)$ of representations of the dihedral group $D_4$ of order 8 admits three distinct fiber functors. Therefore, there are three different Hopf algebras that one can associate with this category. The first one, obviously, is the Hopf group algebra $\mathbb{C}[D_4]$. The other two are then Drinfeld twists of this group algebra. Are there any explicit/concrete constructions of the Drinfeld twists $J_1,J_2\in \mathbb{C}[D_4]\otimes \mathbb{C}[D_4]$ representing such Hopf algebras (or equivalently, are the other two Hopf algebras themselves constructed anywhere)?

I presume this question isn't what are the other two Hopf algebra structures on the algebra $\mathbb{C}D_4\cong \mathbb{C}^4\oplus M_2(\mathbb{C})$?

Ideally, I would like to know what are the Drinfeld twists that give you the other two fiber functors starting from the Hopf algebra $\mathbb{C}[D_4]$. Usually, twists of Hopf algebras only give quasi-Hopf algebras so I would expect to see a non-trivial associator. I should note I am not talking about $\mathbb{C}[Q_8]$ and $H_8$, as their rep categories are only linear equivalent but not tensor equivalent to $\text{Rep}(D_4)$.

I don't understand this claim about fiber functors, which I think contradicts some versions of the Tannaka-Krein theorem depending on what you mean by "fiber functor." Is it that you only require fiber functors to be monoidal but not symmetric monoidal?

Apologies, I forgot about this subtlety. In some places (as in Deligne's papers), tensor already involves a symmetric braiding. In other places, such as EGNO's Tensor categories, a symmetric braiding is an additional structure on a tensor category. I am using this latter definition.
